# How to pause a thread after n minutes

Tags: android, multithreading, runnable, android-handler

I am using runnable and handler. I want to rotate the view at the same time.

This is my source:

```
public void rotateImage(final View myView, final int size) {
    myHandler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int time = (2 * 60 * 1000) / 150;
            if (size > time) {
                myHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
                return;
            }
            myView.setRotation(myView.getRotation() + size);
            rotateImage(myView, size);
        }
    };
    myHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 150);
}
```

It's working, and I can rotate the view every 150 milliseconds, but now I want to pause/stop the thread, for example after two minutes.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can calculate the number of iteration you need to get to 2mins, and change you runnable this way

```
   @Override
   public void run() {
        if (currentIteration > mTotalIterations) {
            myHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
            currentIteration = 0;
            return;
        }
        ++currentIteration;
        myView.setRotation(myView.getRotation() + size);
        rotateImage(myView, size);
        myHandler.postDelayed(this, 150); 
    }
```

you have to create only one runnable and only one handler

Comment: thanks but what is this ? currentIteration > mTotalIterations

Comment: @viviano `mTotalIterations` would be `(2min * 60 * 1000) / 150ms` which is `800` and `currentIteration` is a variable that you need to increment every time you call `run()`

Comment: @ Pedro Oliveira i updated my source.but it not working. after 2 min i can't stop rotation

Comment: @viviano remember that `currentIteration` must be a field and not a variable since you're calling a recursive function. Declare it outside of the function. Like `mTotalIterations`.

Comment: you are doing it wrong. `int time=(2 * 60 * 1000) / 150;` has to be a constant, and it is the total number of iterations to cover two mins. Then you have to keep another member that counts the number of iterations